# How can I recover a deleted comment on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I accidentally deleted someone's comment.

Is there a way to restore it?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that once a comment has been deleted, it is gone. However, if the comment was crucial you could always message the person to see if they would be willing to retype the comment.